# Сравнение даты и времени

Tags: дата, время, php

Как лучше сравнивать даты?

1. Как string? "2012-04-29 23:00:01"
2. как int? 1335726001
3. другое?

Comment: Ответ зависит от тыщи мильонов вещей :) Откуда берутся даты, как хранятся, что именно с ними предполагается делать. Может, их вообще сравнивать не надо, потому что имеет смысл использовать INTERVAL в базе. А может нужно их преобразовывать в/из RFC 3339...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы их хранил и сравнивал как int. Так и памяти выделяется меньше, и сравнение быстрее, и, в отличие от строк, их можно легко привести к любому нужному формату. Впрочем, [@klopp](/users/6550/klopp) очень правильно сказал - это сильно зависит от того, что вы с ними будете делать.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю функция time() просто не заменима в данной ситуации, во первых она создаёт int значение даты, во вторых, вы всегда можете перевести её в нормальный(человеческий) вид, а так же посчитать разницу между датами, пусть даже и в отрицательных значениях. Google - time PHP